# Count the occurence of 'B' in a String S, provided all A's are together

Tags: java

Problem Statement

you are given a string of characters A's and B's
you want all A's to be together,
to achieve this you can delete some B's from the string,
What is the minimum number of B's you can delete to achieve this

Input :: The First and only Argument is string A

Output :: Return an Integer,equal to minimum number of B's you have to delete.

```
Example String s1 =  "AAABA"      SOP(" output=1B is to be deleted, ")
Example String s2 =  "AAAAB"      SOP(" output=0B is to be deleted, All A's are together.");
Example String s3 =  "AAABBBBA "  SOP(" output= 4B is to be deleted")
Example String s4 =  "AAAAAAAAAB" SOP(" output =0B is to be deleted,All A's are together")
```

I have implemented this partialy, but can you point out
where I'm wrong

Initial Analysis of the algorithm :: I'm iterating the string s1 and I'm trying to find the position of the `lastCharacter` which is equal to 'A', I am trying to find the the position of B and increment the output,hence keep a count of output and then display the result which is displaying the wrong result. Where am I going wrong? Could you give me pointers to achieve the desired result as stated in Problem Statement

```
import java.util.*;


    class AlgorithmInJava{

       public static void main(String args[]){

        /* Testing Scenarios */

        String s1= "AAABBBBA";          

        // print output =4B

        int output = 0;

        int n = s1.length();

        char lastCharacter = s1.charAt(n-1);

        System.out.println(" The Last Character is "+lastCharacter);

        int lastCharacterIndex = s1.lastIndexOf(lastCharacter);

        System.out.println("index of lastCharacter :: "+lastCharacterIndex);

         

        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){

          if(lastCharacter == 'A' && s1.charAt(i) == 'B'){

           output++;

           System.out.println(" B output is "+output);

          }else{

          // All A's are together,print output = 0;

           System.out.println(" All A's are together,hence B output is :: "+output);

         }

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: You will enter the `else` clause as soon as you find two consecutive 'A's. What about checking whether `output` is > 0 *after* the loop?

Comment: Also shouldn't `lastCharacter` be first initialized with the value of the *first* character of the string? At which point you start the loop from 1, not from 0.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger to understand what your code is doing.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca im trying this a lot, i have written partial code. Can you please post the code

Comment: @deepakl.2000 I think I gave you more than enough guidance. If you were able to write the code above you'll be able to write the code with the directions I gave you. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: How about a finite state automaton?

Comment: Im trying, give me some time @FedericoklezCulloca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is to count consecutive `B` until we find an `A`. Steps I have followed

1. Keep track of how many `B` I have found till I find an 'A'.
2. If `A` found then add the `B Count` to the main `output` and reset the value for the next consecutive searching.
3. If `A` not found then simply discard the `B Count` tracker.

```
//Removing the first and last unnecessary B
String s1 = "BBBAAAABBBBAABB";
s1= s1.substring(s1.indexOf("A"),s1.lastIndexOf("A"));

int output=0;
int bFound=0;
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
  if(s1.charAt(i)=='B'){
    System.out.println("B Found");
    bFound++;
  }else if(bFound>0 && s1.charAt(i)=='A'){
    output+=bFound; //adding to main output plus resetting the count  
    bFound=0;
  }
}

System.out.println("Total B to remove: "+output);
if(output>0){
  // your print statement
}else{
  // your print statement
}
```

Comment: String s1= "BBBABAABBBBABB"; // output 5 but returns 8 in your case

Comment: My bad did not think of this one. I will update my ans .

Comment: your print statements are also empty

Comment: I believe you can add those lines on your own as per your need.

Comment: if(output > 0){ System.out.println(" B output is "+output); } else{ System.out.println(" All A's are together,hence B output is :: " + output); } is giving output 1 , should give output 5 for String s1= "BBBABAABBBBABB"; // output 5

Comment: if(output > 0){ System.out.println(" B output is "+output); } else{ System.out.println(" All A's are together,hence B output is :: " + output); } is giving output 1 , should give output 5 for String s1= "BBBABAABBBBABB"; // output 5

Comment: Sorry I didn't compiled the code yesterday and made another mistake. Can your try 
`s1= s1.substring(s1.indexOf("A"),s1.lastIndexOf("A")+1)` . I think that will solve the issue. I will check as soon as I get a hold of my laptop.

Comment: Can you solve my another problem.plz share email id

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe too advanced for you to understand, but you can get the count with a single line like this

```
String s1= "BBBABAABBBBABB"; // output 5          
long count = Pattern.compile("(?<=(A.{0,100}))B(?=(.*A))").matcher(s1).results().count();
if(count > 0){
    System.out.println(" B output is " + count);
} else{
    System.out.println(" All A's are together,hence  B output is :: " + count);
}
```

It uses a Regex that matches all B's that have an A at some point before and after it by using a lookahead and lookbehind.
`100` is an arbitrary number that should be equal to or higher than the max length of the expected string.

Comment: Might be simpler/safer to remove leading|trailing Bs and then just count all remaining Bs. I'm no Java coder, in Python I'd do `s.strip('B').count('B')`.

Comment: I guess in Java, at least `Pattern.compile("B").matcher(s1.replaceAll("^B+|B+$").results().count()` should work (untested, as I'm on a phone and despise writing Java anyway :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy good point, that's probably a better approach

Comment: @IvoBeckers i have a problem, can i email you ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: remove the lone B's from the left and right. Then count the B's in the middle.

```java
    public static int minDeletion(String s){
        int counter = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int right = s.length()-1;
        while(true){
            if(s.charAt(left)=='B') left++;
            if(s.charAt(right)=='B') right--;
            if(s.charAt(left)!='B' && s.charAt(right)!='B') break;
        }
        for(int i=left; i<=right; i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='B') counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Assign two pointers, one starting from the left and the other from the right end. `left` will move to the right and `right` will move to the left until A is found in both. After that, count the Bs in that section as they have to be removed for all As to be consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Bro

```
package app;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s1 = "AAABA";
        int neededToDelete = 0;
        int subIndexToDeleteTo = s1.length();
        for (int i = s1.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (Objects.equals('B', s1.charAt(i)) && s1.substring(0, i).contains("A") &&
            s1.substring(i, subIndexToDeleteTo).contains("B") && i != s1.length()-1) {
                neededToDelete++;
                subIndexToDeleteTo  = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(neededToDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should return 5 not 6                                    
 String s1= "BBBABAABBBBABB"; // output 5